# Parallel-hashmap: determining C++ version

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, deprecated, c++20

I build a program using `parallel-hashmap` package taken from the latest `vcpkg` in Visual Studio 2019 with `stdcpplatest` flag (activating C++20 standard) and get an error

```
>C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\parallel_hashmap\phmap_base.h(335,39): error C2039: 'result_of': is not a member of 'std'
```

In the code as follows

```
template< class F, class... ArgTypes>
#if __cplusplus >= 201703L
using invoke_result_t = typename std::invoke_result_t<F, ArgTypes...>;
#else
using invoke_result_t = typename std::result_of<F(ArgTypes...)>::type;
#endif
```

So it is not correct to use `#if __cplusplus >= 201703L` to determine the existence of `result_of` replacement. And what is the right way then?

Comment: [`result_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) was deprecated, then removed.

Comment: "Correct" is one thing, "supported by your compiler" is another.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-cplusplus?view=msvc-160

Comment: [result_of Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/result-of-class?view=msvc-160): Added in C++14, deprecated in C++17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As n. 'pronouns' m. suggested in the comment above, one has to add command line option `/Zc:__cplusplus` to Visual Studio compiler, which will set proper value to `__cplusplus` macro.

The other option is to write the check as follows:

```
#if (defined(_MSVC_LANG) && _MSVC_LANG >= 201703) || __cplusplus >= 201703
```

which will be compatible both with Visual Studio and any other compiler.